# Laravel filesystem get file URL directly after upload

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to get the path of the file you uploaded directly after you upload it so you won't have to write the whole URL in the response, my approach is certainly not correct because what if in the future we might want to save in another filesystem disk which is not in storage, i want to return the specific URL.

```
        $image = interventionImage::make(request('url'))->resize(600, 300, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->encode('webp', 75);


        $time = date('H-i-s');

        $date = date('d-m-Y');

        Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/products/'.$date.'/'.$time.'.webp', $image);
        

        return response()->json([
            'success' => 1, 
            'file' => [
                'url' => asset('/storage/uploads/products/'.$date.'/'.$time.'.webp')
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

put the path in a variable?

```
        $image = interventionImage::make(request('url'))->resize(600, 300, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->encode('webp', 75);

        $path = sprintf('uploads/products/%s/%s.webp',date('d-m-Y'),date('H-i-s'));

        Storage::disk($path, $image);
        

        return response()->json([
            'success' => 1, 
            'file' => [
                'url' => $path
            ]
        ]);
```

Don't use time as a unique indicator if multiple files can be uploaded in the same second (ie with multiple on file input)

Comment: Yes i thought of that, but what if i want to upload to another disk, S3 for example? I will have to write different path variables for each disk which is not efficient.

Comment: Because you don't specify the disk, the upload will go to the default disk.  You can change the default disk at any time. However it would be better to create a disk called 'products' in the filesystems config file.  Then at any time, change the disk in config to be a different location.  Better to only store just the filename in the database as at present you would have to replicate the same folder structure in cloud storage.

Comment: Pretty nice, although it would be great if there was a method returning the exact path of the file after uploading, i will be waiting if anyone has a solution.

Comment: There would not be 'an exact path' if the file was uploaded to the cloud?

Comment: Of course the would be an exact path. By exact path i mean the full URL pointing to the file.

Comment: There might be a url pointing to the file, not a path. The path is only relative to the file system provider.